# Why is this only showing 3 blocks per row instead of 4?

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/Tollens/pen/wvvodod

I want the option buttons at the bottom for 1,2,3,4 to be in one row, but it wraps the 4 to the next row. How can I solve this problem? For some reason Stack Overflow needs me to over explain this. So what I have are 3 rows of options

```
Row 1: OTCBB, NYSE, NASDAQ
Row 2: DAY, WEEK, MONTH
Row 3: 1,2,3,4
```

Row 3 wraps the option 4 to the next row, but I want it to be in the same row. What do I need to modify in the css to accomplish this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #eee;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 200;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2fcc71;
  max-width: 40%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}


/* CONTAINERS */

.container {
  max-width: 850px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.four {
  width: 32.26%;
  max-width: 32.26%;
}

.more {
  width: 66%
}


/* COLUMNS */

.col {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.col:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}


/* CLEARFIX */

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}


/* FORM */

.form .plan input,
.form .payment-plan input,
.form .payment-type input {
  display: none;
}

.form label {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #aaa;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form .plan input:checked+label,
.form .payment-plan input:checked+label,
.form .payment-type input:checked+label {
  border: 3px solid #333;
  background-color: #2fcc71;
}

.form .plan input:checked+label:after,
form .payment-plan input:checked+label:after,
.form .payment-type input:checked+label:after {
  content: "\2713";
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  background-color: #2fcc71;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
}

.submit {
  padding: 15px 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background-color: #2fcc71;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.submit:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotateX(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>RideStock</h1>
  <form class="form cf">
    <section class="plan cf">

      <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="free" value="free"><label class="free-label four col" for="free">OTCBB</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="basic" value="basic" checked><label class="basic-label four col" for="basic">NYSE</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="premium" value="premium"><label class="premium-label four col" for="premium">NASDAQ</label>
    </section>
    <section class="payment-plan cf">
      <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="monthly" value="monthly" checked><label class="monthly-label four col" for="monthly">Day</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="yearly" value="yearly"><label class="yearly-label four col" for="yearly">Week</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="yearly" value="yearly"><label class="yearly-label four col" for="yearly">Month</label>
    </section>
    <section class="payment-type cf more">
      <input type="radio" name="radio3" id="credit" value="credit"><label class="credit-label four col" for="credit">1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio3" id="debit" value="debit"><label class="debit-label four col" for="debit">2</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio3" id="paypal" value="paypal" checked><label class="paypal-label four col" for="paypal">3</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio3" id="other" value="paypal" checked><label class="paypal-label four col" for="paypal">4</label>

    </section>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created `.four` class with `32.26%` and used that in all three rows. That is OK for three options. But when you use that same class for 4 options, total percentage exceeds 100. So the fourth option going to the next line.

I have created `.three` class with `32.26%` and `.four` class with `25%`.

And used `.three` class for the first 2 rows and `.four` class for the third row

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #eee;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 200;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2fcc71;
  max-width: 40%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}


/* CONTAINERS */

.container {
  max-width: 850px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.four {
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
  }

.three {
  width: 32.26%;
  max-width: 32.26%;
}

.more {
  width: 66%
}


/* COLUMNS */

.col {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.col:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}


/* CLEARFIX */

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}


/* FORM */

.form .plan input,
.form .payment-plan input,
.form .payment-type input {
  display: none;
}

.form label {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #aaa;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form .plan input:checked+label,
.form .payment-plan input:checked+label,
.form .payment-type input:checked+label {
  border: 3px solid #333;
  background-color: #2fcc71;
}

.form .plan input:checked+label:after,
form .payment-plan input:checked+label:after,
.form .payment-type input:checked+label:after {
  content: "\2713";
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  background-color: #2fcc71;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
}

.submit {
  padding: 15px 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background-color: #2fcc71;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.submit:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotateX(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>RideStock</h1>
  <form class="form cf">
    <section class="plan cf">

      <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="free" value="free"><label class="free-label three col" for="free">OTCBB</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="basic" value="basic" checked><label class="basic-label three col" for="basic">NYSE</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="premium" value="premium"><label class="premium-label three col" for="premium">NASDAQ</label>
    </section>
    <section class="payment-plan cf">
      <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="monthly" value="monthly" checked><label class="monthly-label three col" for="monthly">Day</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="yearly" value="yearly"><label class="yearly-label three col" for="yearly">Week</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="yearly" value="yearly"><label class="yearly-label three col" for="yearly">Month</label>
    </section>
    <section class="payment-type cf more">
      <input type="radio" name="radio3" id="credit" value="credit"><label class="credit-label four col" for="credit">1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio3" id="debit" value="debit"><label class="debit-label four col" for="debit">2</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio3" id="paypal" value="paypal" checked><label class="paypal-label four col" for="paypal">3</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio3" id="other" value="paypal" checked><label class="paypal-label four col" for="paypal">4</label>

    </section>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to put place-holders in sections "payment-plan cf" "plan cf" ? I'm not used to use web coding but as far as i can tell you either need to put a place holder or need to values like "colspan".